# useState hook with callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The app below has two buttons, both changing the same state, but has different callbacks.

My question is how do I achieve the same result with hooks with functional components? I have seen some custom hooks like `useStatewithCallback`, which is essentially the same as below

```
useEffect(()=>{
   /*some side effect here*/
}[counter])
```

The problem with that approach is that `useEffect` only knows if `counter` has changed, but not what changed it. If I were to do that, then the same side effect will fire (aka same callback).

What I need is something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
   /*if first button clicked, run first side effect*/
   /*if second button clicked, run second side effect*/
}[counter])
```

So the only think I can think of right now is to add states to the buttons, then rewrite the useEffects.

Is there an easier way?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0};
  }
  
  clickFirst = ()=>{
    this.setState({counter:this.state.counter + 1},
    ()=>{
      console.log('first button clicked')
      console.log(`the counter is now ${this.state.counter}`)
    })
  }
  
  clickSecond = ()=>{
    this.setState({counter:this.state.counter + 1},
    ()=>{
      console.log('second button clicked')
      console.log(`the counter is now ${this.state.counter}`)
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickFirst}>{this.state.counter}</button>
        <button onClick={this.clickSecond}>{this.state.counter}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
const App = () => {
  const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);
  const [ buttonClicked, setButtonClicked ] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (buttonClicked == "firstButton") {
        // do some stuff
      } else if (buttonClicked == "secondButton") {
        // do some stuff
      }
    },
    [ buttonClicked, counter ]
  );

  clickFirst = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    setButtonClicked("firstButton");
  };

  clickSecond = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    setButtonClicked("secondButton");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickFirst}>{counter}</button>
      <button onClick={clickSecond}>{counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The problem is that, if I click the same button multiple times, the effect won't trigger because `buttonClicked ` is the same

Comment: Ok then you should add the [counter] dependency. I have updated the answer.